# for loop over a tibble in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, for-loop, tibble

WORKING ON RSTUDIO

SO, I have the basic dataset of titanic.csv, which has the fifth column as Age.
What I'm trying to do is store that **entire column of age** in a variable and run a for loop on it.
When I try doing so, it shows that the variable is a tibble.

the command that I used to read the csv file and store it in a variable named **tata** is:

```
tata <- read_csv("titanic.csv")
```

*the csv file is in the same directory as the **.r** file, so reading the file ain't any issue here.*

getting the fifth column of **age** in a variable **x**

```
x <- tata[,5]
```

when I print x I get this in the console:

[image: console window]

Then I try to get a multiple line print statement that says: **The nth person has age: *(the variable_value)***

```
for (age in x) {
  print(paste("The", n , "th person has age:", age))
  n = n + 1
}
```

I GET THE OUTPUT AS:

```
  [1] "The 1 th person has age 22"   "The 1 th person has age 38"  
  [3] "The 1 th person has age 26"   "The 1 th person has age 35"  
  [5] "The 1 th person has age 35"   "The 1 th person has age 27"  
  [7] "The 1 th person has age 54"   "The 1 th person has age 2"   
  [9] "The 1 th person has age 27"   "The 1 th person has age 14"  
 [11] "The 1 th person has age 4"    "The 1 th person has age 58"
```

and this goes on till 887 rows

I hope you understand what I need here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have casted the data to a `tibble` (i.e., `read_csv` and not `read.csv`) you need to call

```r
x <- tata$Age
```

instead of

```r
x <- tata[, 5]
```

This is as the latter returns a tibble again and thus `paste(..., print(x))` works differently than what you'd expect.

## Addendum

for loops are usually a bad idea in R. Have a look at the `*apply` family of functions or the `purrr` package.

E.g.,

```r
library(dplyr)
tata %>%
  pull(Age) %>%
  sapply(function(age) paste("Person is", age, "years old"))
```

Comment: usually this is a good idea (imho) as it does not convert strings to factors and is faster/more robust. But you need to be careful, that `df[, "somevar"]` returns a tibble and not a vector!

Comment: sir, I am getting an error as "invalid path argument". First, it was "could not find function  'pull' in R". I solved it by installing and activating a package named "git2r". I am glad that u tried to help me, but it didn't work, It'll be appreciable if u wish to assist me on this further

Comment: `pull` is a function of `dplyr` not `git2r`... Sorry I should have included that! Edited it!

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can do most of the things without loop.

For example, here you can try `paste` which is vectorized.

```
x <- unlist(x)
paste("The ", seq_along(x), "th person has age ", x)
```

Or with `for` loop

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
   cat("\nThe ", i, "th person has age ", x[i])
}
```